# SQL Query: New columns for data with some matching criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, multiple-columns

I'm working with a query that pulls data from a table and arranges it in a manner similar to below:

```
Query1

BldID  UnitID   Res1

1      201      John Smith   
1      201      Jane Doe
1      202      Daniel Jones
1      202      Mark Garcia
2      201      Maria Lee
2      201      Paul Williams
2      201      Mike Jones
```

I'd like to modify the query output in SQL/Design so that each resident that shares a building / unit shows as a new column on the same row as shown below:

```
BldID  UnitID   Res1          Res2           Res3 
1      201      John Smith    Jane Doe
1      202      Daniel Jones  Mark Garcia
2      201      Maria Lee     Paul Williams  Mike Jones
```

I apologize if this is crude/not enough information but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `conditional aggregation`

```
with cte as
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by BldID,UnitID order by Res1) as rn
from tablename
)

select BldID,UnitID,
       max(case when rn=1 then Res1 end) as Res1,
       max(case when rn=2 then Res1 end) as Res2,
       max(case when rn=3 then Res1 end) as Res3
from cte
group by BldID,UnitID
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Fahmi. I suppose I should have elaborated more. The Resident field is essentially all unique entries. Each resident has a different name. Would this affect the result, and if so what would I use to select unique individuals to achieve the same result?

Comment: @llOmni, could you please revise your sample to indicate this uniqueness, and better articulate what is desired? Under these two conditions, getting a solid dynamic columns from MSAcess this way might involve more operators than you're used to, and likely makes use of a subquery to get the proper results out.

Comment: @JaazCole I apologize since it was not formatted this way to begin with. I have removed the generic A, B, C identifiers with some Stock Names in the format of output I'm looking for. So far as a clarifying statement, all I can add is each building/unit is a unique entity with multiple residents in each. 1/1 1/2 1/3, 2/1/ 2/2 2/3, and I'm trying to space out those residents since right now they are all listed under Res1. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @llOmni, I've updated the asnwer - you can give a try now

Comment: @JaazCole and Fahmi I've been trying both answers, and so far no luck. It is probably on my end since I'm still new with SQL. Faami when putting in your data I'm being hit with an Invalid SQL Statement. It seems to not like something regarding the CTE structure. JaazCole I'll be honest you are above my head on this one. Tablename as T1 and Tablename as T2 are in regards to what tables? Even if I am pulling from my original query am I supposed to substitute this as both the T1 and T2 table or should I be pulling from the original table and the query from it? Again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So, drawing from a few different sources, this might work, try pasting this intoa  query editor, and see if it'll run.

```
TRANSFORM MAX(Res1)
SELECT BldID, UnitID
    , (
         SELECT COUNT(T1.Marks)
         FROM tableName AS T1
         WHERE 
             T1.BldgID = T2.BldgID AND
             T1.UnitID = T2.UnitID AND
             T1.Res1 >= T2.Res1
      ) AS Rank, Res1
FROM tableName t2
GROUP BY BldID, UnitID
PIVOT Rank;
```

Answer (score 0):

2 years late, but maybe I can add something, in Access we are surgeons operating with kitchen knifes, things must be done in the Access Way...

I tested it having this table **UnitStudentBlock**

| BldID | UnitID | Res1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 201 | John Smith |
| 1 | 201 | Jane Doe |
| 1 | 202 | Daniel Jones |
| 1 | 202 | Mark Garcia |
| 2 | 201 | Maria Lee |
| 2 | 201 | Paul Williams |
| 2 | 201 | Mike Jones |
| 2 | 201 | Julian Gomes |

As Access doesn't have row_number, first I created a table with an auto increment field so that we can have something like a row number:

```
CREATE TABLE TableWithId
(
Id COUNTER,
BldID  INT,
UnitID INT,
Res1 VARCHAR(100),
ResNumber VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Then I inserted all the data from the initial table into this newly created table:

```
INSERT INTO TableWithId (BldID, UnitID, Res1)
SELECT * 
FROM UnitStudentBlock
ORDER BY BldID, 
         UnitID
```

Then I updated everything using DCOUNT to have a row_number partitioned:

```
UPDATE TableWithId
SET ResNumber = 'Res' + Cstr(DCOUNT("*", "TableWithId", "ID >=" & [ID] 
                                                     & " AND UnitId = " & [UnitId] 
                                                     & " AND BldId = " & [BldId]))
```

And finally we can run the query that returns the data:

```
TRANSFORM MAX(Res1)
SELECT BldID, UnitID
FROM TableWithId
GROUP BY BldID, UnitID 
PIVOT ResNumber
```